# Prove that each component of $X$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Definition: Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\sim_C$ be the equivalence relation on $X$ defined by $x \sim_C y$ if $x$ and $y$ lie in a connected subset of $X$. The components of $X$ are the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $\sim_C$.

Question: Prove that each component of $X$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Please guide me how to start to prove, or any clue. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I came up with a simpler proof: That components are the largest connected subsets of $X$; I choose one of them, say $C$. Since C is connected in X, thus so is $Cl(C)$. Thus $C=Cl(C)$ and then $C$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C$ be a connected component. Let $x\in X$ be outside $C$; then $B=C\cup \{x\}$ is not connected. Let $U,V$ form a separation of $B$. Suppose $x\in U$; I claim that $U\cap C=\emptyset$. If not, then $U\cap C,V\cap C$ would form a separation of $C$, which is not possible since $C$ is connected. Thus $U\cap C=\emptyset$, hence $C$ is closed since its complement is open.

Comment: Thank you but I have some problems in understanding your proof: If $y\in U$, "then" why $U$ doesn't contain $x$? and, Why "the complement of the component containing $x$ is open"? BTW, $X$ can be partitioned into more than two components. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @alphae try my edit.

Comment: Sorry the phone is very bad with saving edits during things like screen rotation, should be fixed.

Comment: But, how you know $U\cap C$ and $V\cap C$ are open?

Comment: @Pot Even though they are, they don't have to be for the argument, but in the subspace topology they are obviously open in $C$, which is enough.

Comment: thanks! i forgot that